# How to find unnecessary variable setup in tests using RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Suppose I have a set of tests like the following. Apparently, test1 and test2 should be separated so that the preparation of var1 or var2 will not be unnecessary in test2 or test1. Anyway I can use some static analysis tool to find out? I have looked at Rubocop and did not find it has rules to spot this problem.

```
# I want to give whatever writes this code
# some warning: the tests have unnecessary 
# variable setup

describe "all_tests" do
  before do
    @var1 = 1 # suppose these two lines
    @var2 = 2 # are very expensive
  end
  
  it "test1" do
    expect(@var1).to eq(1)
  end

  it "test2" do
    expect(@var2).to eq(2)
  end
end
```

I have looked at Rubocop, hoping to find any rule in Rubocop that can spot this problem and give a warning. But I did not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you switched to the [`let`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/MemoizedHelpers/ClassMethods#let-instance_method) syntax, then:

1. The problem will not exist anymore, because variables get only set, evaluated and memorized when actually called.
2. And `rubocop-rspec` would find defined `let` declarations that are not used in any expectation.

```
describe "all_tests" do
  let(:var1) { 1 }
  let(:var2) { 2 }
  let(:var3) { 3 } # rubocop-rspec would find this

  it "test1" do
    expect(var1).to eq(1)
  end

  it "test2" do
    expect(var2).to eq(2)
  end
end
```